# How to prevent usernames from containing @/./+/-/_.?

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I'm using [django-allauth](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html), and for some reason the username default allows:

"letters, digits and @/./+/-/_."

How can I ensure usernames are strictly alphanumeric (without `@/./+/-/_.`)?

I'm already using this `clean_username()` validator which currently works:

```
class UsernameMaxAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):

    def clean_username(self, username):
        exclude = ['@', '/', '.', '+', '-', '/', '_', ',']
        if len(username) > 20:
            raise ValidationError("Username can't be over 20 characters")
        for i in exclude:
            if i in username:
                raise ValidationError("Use only alphanumeric characters")
        return DefaultAccountAdapter.clean_username(self,username) # For other default validations.
```

Edit: Just realised both the validators are not working...trying to find the problem now..

Comment: Is username just a normal string?

Comment: Also, what exactly does `clean_username()` do?

Comment: Overwrites the default `clean_username()` for customization I believe. However if you see my edit, my 2nd function with `exclude` did not work (it still created the profile while using those characters).

Comment: Surely it didn't work because you still `return`ed the original username afterwards?

Comment: forgot to set `ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'app.forms.UsernameMaxAdapter'` in my settings.py which prevented my adapter function from executing. thanks for the help it's working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think python's builtin function [**`str.isalnum()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalnum) could be usefull here.

```
class UsernameMaxAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):
    def clean_username(self, username):
        # assumes "username" is a type of "str" object
        if not username.isalnum():
            raise ValidationError("Use only alphanumeric characters")
        # your logic
```

**UPDATE-1**
set `ACCOUNT_USERNAME_VALIDATORS` in settings.py as mentioned in [documentation](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html)

```
class CustomValidator(object):

    def __call__(self, username="", *args, **kwargs):
        username = username.isalnum()
        if not username:
            raise ValidationError("Use only alphanumeric characters")
```

in your `settings.py`,

```
custom_username_validators = [CustomValidator()]
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_VALIDATORS = 'path.to.settings.custom_username_validators'
```

Comment: I used this and I don't know why but it is still creating the profile.

Comment: forgot to set `ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'app.forms.UsernameMaxAdapter'` in my settings.py. works perfect now thanks!

Comment: Wow..that's cool. Anyway I updated the answer with `CustomValidator` class.You could try that also

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used `django` and certainly don't know about its authorisation mechanisms, but I know that in plain `python`, if you wanted to carry this out, you could simply sanitise input by doing:

```
newUserName = ''.join(ch for ch in oldUserName if ch.isalnum())
```

Essentially, I'm looping through each character and am appending them to the 'clean' username if the character is alphanumeric.

In your function, if the username doesn't comply with the alphanumeric restrictions, execute the statement above (place it under the `if`).

Comment: The initial function is now not working so I am trying to get that fixed (once that works the alphanumeric validator code should work) - but I can't put `break` below `if len(username) > 20:`, it is not allowed (`break` outside loop)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) expression to ensure that a username contains only allowed characters. For alphanumeric characters the following should do the trick:

```
import re
def is_valid_username(username):
    pattern = re.compile('([a-zA-Z]+|\d+)')
    return ''.join(re.findall(pattern, username)) == username
```

Here's an example of the output:

```
username_list = ["WhatAGre4tUsern4me", "548ThatISAgoodUsername005",
                 "CheckOutMy_Username", "It'sAUsern@me"]
print([is_valid_username(u) for u in username_list])
>>> [True, True, False, False]
```

Comment: I have used this in my `clean_username()` function but it is still creating the profile - not sure why.